# Cookies in errors pages

Tags: laravel, cookies

My method in controller (Laravel)

```
public function nightmode()
{
    return back()->withCookie(cookie()->forever('night_mode', Cookie::get('night_mode') == TRUE ? FALSE:TRUE));
}
```

in view

```
@if(Cookie::get('night_mode'))
    // code
@endif
```

this works on all pages, but on custom error pages, instead of the value of the cookies, this returns their hash

Comment: in config/session.php
**'path' => '/'**

Answer (score 0):

answer

```
\Crypt::decrypt($request->cookie('night_mode'))
```